# Javascript Callback in for Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, callback

My problem is that I'm having a `Function A` which calls at one point another function, let's call it `Function B` (getChildContent) and needs the return value of `Function B` in order to proceed. I know that it's because of Javascripts Asynchronous Nature, and i tried to solve it with a callback. But i can't get it work properly.

```
FunctionA(){
//some Code.....
else {
        for(i in clustertitles) {
            if(S(text).contains(clustertitles[i])) {
                var parent = {};
                parent.ClusterName = clustertitles[i];
                parent.Functions = [];
                var str = '== ' + clustertitles[i] + ' ==\n* ';
                str = S(text).between(str,'.').s;
                var caps = parseFunctions(str);
                for(y in caps) {
                    //var content = getChildContent(caps[y]);
                    getChildContent(caps[y], function(content) { //Function call
                        var child = {};
                        child.FunctionName = caps[y];
                        child.Content = [];
                        child.Content.push(content);
                        parent.Functions.push(child);       
                        console.log(content);
                    });
                }}}
}

function getChildContent (capname, callback) {
t = capname.replace(' ', '_');
bot.page(t).complete(function (title, text, date) {
    var str = S(text).between('== Kurzbeschreibung ==\n* ', '.').s;
        if(str === undefined || str === null || str === '') {
            throw new Error('Undefined, Null or Empty!');
        }
        else {
            var content = {};
            str = parseTitles(str);
            content.Owner = str[0];
            content.Aim = str[1];
            content.What = str[2];
            content.Who = str[3];
            content.Steps = str[4];
            content.Page = 'some URL';
            callback(content);
        }
});
```

}

So in `Function A` I'm trying to call getChildContent from a for-Loop and pass the current string from caps-array. For each String in caps-array getChildContent() makes a http request over a node.js module and retrieves a string. With this string i'm building an object (content) which is needed in `Function A` to continue. However the 'console.log(content)' in `Function A` just prints out the object which is created with the last string in caps-array, but for many times. E.G. if caps-array has 5 entries, i get 5 times the object which is created with the last entry of caps-array.
How can i manage the loop/callback to get every time the right object on my console?

Comment: This won't work. When your callback function is called your y variable has changed its value.

Comment: Have your tried `Function.prototype.bind`?

Comment: @ EugenTimm i know that it's not working, do u have any hints to make it work?

Comment: @klenium sry i'm new to javascript, don't know what u r trying to tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should call another function that preserves the value of y, something like this:

```
FunctionA(){
//some Code.....
else {
  for(i in clustertitles) {
      if(S(text).contains(clustertitles[i])) {
          var parent = {};
          parent.ClusterName = clustertitles[i];
          parent.Functions = [];
          var str = '== ' + clustertitles[i] + ' ==\n* ';
          str = S(text).between(str,'.').s;
          var caps = parseFunctions(str);
          for(y in caps) {
              yourNewFunction (y, caps, parent);
          }}}
}

function yourNewFunction (y, caps, parent) {
  getChildContent(caps[y], function(content) { //Function call
      var child = {};
      child.FunctionName = caps[y];
      child.Content = [];
      child.Content.push(content);
      parent.Functions.push(child);       
      console.log(content);
  });
}

function getChildContent (capname, callback) {
t = capname.replace(' ', '_');
bot.page(t).complete(function (title, text, date) {
    var str = S(text).between('== Kurzbeschreibung ==\n* ', '.').s;
        if(str === undefined || str === null || str === '') {
            throw new Error('Undefined, Null or Empty!');
        }
        else {
            var content = {};
            str = parseTitles(str);
            content.Owner = str[0];
            content.Aim = str[1];
            content.What = str[2];
            content.Who = str[3];
            content.Steps = str[4];
            content.Page = 'some URL';
            callback(content);
        }
});
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i get the same result by calling another function as u proposed above....

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do so.
Put the loop inside a function, execute your callback after the loop is done. (Problematic if you are doing async call inside the loop.

```
function doLoopdiloopStuff() {
 for() {
 }
 callback();
}
```

The other way, the way i prefer looks like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < stuff || function(){ /* here's the callback */ }(), false; i++) {
  /* do your loop-di-loop */ 
}
```

In another example:

```
for (var index = 0; index < caps.length || function(){ callbackFunction(); /* This is the callback you are calling */ return false;}(); index++) {
            var element = caps[index];
            // here comes the code of what you want to do with a single element
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but im struggling to convert your hint to my example.... in my example above 'stuff' would be 'caps.length' right? the part after '||' is not quite clear to me....

Comment: Yup. Stuff is your caps.length. The "||" is the or in this form. So is goes through all your items in caps. Afterwards it enters the function. Inside the function you can built your callback. Either return values or call another function from it.

Comment: ok i cant get it work... what i did is just simply writing the getChildContent function after the '||' in the loop.... but it doesnt work.... what do u mean with 'u can built your callback here' .....

Comment: look at the edit. maybe the newly added comments, to the last example help you understand it a bit better.

Comment: thanks for being that patient with me, but i can't figure out how to transfer your example to mine... especially the function in the loop...